# Why executeQuery after refresh takes 100x more time?

Tags: performance-testing, axapta

I have a form with 4 datasources. It is in listpage style and have Datasource1 (big table with lots of relations, columns, and indexes) shown in grid. When I open this form it takes like 200ms to open it but when I refresh it it takes 13s to refresh.

I used the **Code profiler tool** and I find out that the time is consumed in Datasource1 in **executeQuery()** method by command **super();**

When the **executeQuery()** is called from form by

```
Datasource1_ds.executeQuery();
```

it takes 200ms to call it.

There is like 15 columns in grid on form and sorting by one takes a little less than 1s.

So my question is. What is called in **super();** when the form is refreshed by task F5 and not called by openning form and calling **Datasource1_ds.executeQuery();**?

I try to use Code profiler with different setings and actions, debug the code in various action done, use Visual Studio Profiler, use Activity Monitor in Microsoft SQL server on Microsoft Dynamics AX database, changes the Datasource1 table, with no luck.

Everytime I end up on the **super();** Only time when the refresh is fast is when I have filters on the grid and it shows less rows. (I try to use VisibleRows property on grid but it does not help.)

I am using Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R2

Comment: Have you read  [this](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html) great article?

Comment: @MaximLazarev Yes But I have problem with task(#taskF5) method. F5 on form and task method is not modified.

Comment: @boucekv: Do change the sorting in the form before hitting refresh? I ask because data retrievel in a form with a grid is influenced by the cluster index of the tables and if the sorting does not correspond to the cluster index, this could be the cause of the slower data retrieval. You could also take a look at trace parser (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj149695.aspx) and check if the queries between opening the form and refresh are different.

Comment: @FH-Inway I just use Trace Parcer to find problematic query. It is a good tip to look at the query on the opening of the form and compare it. The trace parser returns me query with ? e.g. "(T1.RECID<?)" where ? stands for real value. Is it possible to get 1 query with real values so I can analyze it in SQL Server manager?

Comment: @boucekv: The keyword is "literals" or "force literals". I have not used this in some time, so I would have to do some research of my own, but these links should get you started: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569637.aspx and http://ax.nom.es/dynamicsax/axapta-comman-line-parameters-2. Just do a search on keyword "literal" on these pages.

Comment: Try to add `this.query().literals(true);` after the `super()` in the `init` method of the datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to capture with SQL Server Profiler queries that are executed (1) on initial `executeQuery()` when ListPage form is opened, then (2) on invocation of `executeQuery()` on form refresh.

Comparison of execution plans of these two queries must show the bottleneck. You may capture *Showplan XML* event.

Comment: The problem is in query which are called. They are different. The slow one have 15x more thing is WHERE clausule. Now I am trying to find what to change to change querz which is called when form is refreshed. Without sucess now.